# How to show a waiting overlay in iOS project?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a project I'm writing in iOS and Swift.

I have a button that I press and then an action that takes around 2 seconds before the callback is called (and then I move to the next screen).

I want to block the screen or show a waiting overlay, 
or do something to block the user for those 2 seconds, 
I don't want to open a new view with a spinner and then to move from that to the next one.

How to handle that?

Comment: use UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents() and after getting the callback response do UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

Comment: @vivekDas how does that show a waiting overlay?

Comment: to show progress indicator you can use activity indicator of iso, or 3rd party framework as SVProgressHUD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIActivityIndicatorView`

```
let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: view.bounds)
activityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
activityIndicator.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
activityIndicator.style = .whiteLarge
view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
```

start on button press

```
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

stop after completion and remove the view

```
activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Apple suggests that you show a sort of progress bar or spinner to let the user know that something is in progress. Upon seeing the spinner/progress bar the instinctive reaction of the user would be to wait for it to complete.

My personal advice to you would be to NOT block the user from doing anything. If he wants to click on back button while the response is being fetched from the backend then so be it! Blocking is usually tied to bad UX in eyes of many.

Some of the options would be:

1) Show spinner on same screen and when the data is received proceed to the next screen.

2) Show HUD as shared by Jogendar Choudhary above.

3) Show spinner on the button itself and then proceed once successful.

Options are plenty. Let me know if you have further queries.